# Skipping certain numbers in a sequence

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, sequence, skip

In Excel 2010 I have a list of sequence numbers that have been used previously which I want to reserve, and I need to create a formula that will start with a number I provide as the starting one, but bypass the ones that are on my reserved list.  Both the sequence number and the reserve list numbers can be several thousand entries each. My reserved sequence numbers are:

[image: Reserved Numbers]

If I give my sequence a starting number of 150, I would want my sequence numbers to be assigned as follows:

[image: Sequence numbers that skip reserved ones]

where the sequence skips numbers `156` and `231`.

I have seen a way to create a custom list, but this is just the opposite.

How might I achieve this?

Comment: Do you actually want the "SEQ" text as part of the output numbers?

Comment: @ExcelHero - yes, but it didn't have to be.  Since that's a literal, I could just tack it on after I got the number that skipped the reserved ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell M2 enter this formula:

```
=MAX(start,M1)+1+(IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(start,M1)+1,rsv,),0)>0)
```

and copy downwards.

`start` is the cell with the starting number (K2 in your example).

`rsv` is the list of reserved numbers.

.

**UPDATE**

Here is another formula that overcomes the problem with sequential reserved numbers:

```
=INDEX(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,start-1,,999)),MATCH(1,ISERROR(MATCH(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,start-1,,999)),rsv,))*(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,start-1,,999))>MAX(M1,start)),))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: There's a slight problem with it - it works fine if the reserved numbers are not sequential.  If they are sequential, it does the first one right (and skips it), but the second one uses one of the reserved numbers.

Comment: Ahh I see. That's complicates things a lot. What's the max sequential?

Comment: The number of sequential numbers varies throughout, but at first glance, I don't see any more than 8-10 that are consecutive.

Comment: I believe that the array formula did the trick.  I've thrown several examples at it & they've all worked!   Thank you very much for your help!! :)

Comment: Great! You are welcome. That was a challenging one.  ;)

Comment: One thing. Change the occurrences of `20` in the formula to a much higher number, say 999. I'm making that edit now.

Comment: I changed it when I typed it in.  Put it at several thousand & didn't have a problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your skipped numbers aren't themselves sequential, this formula will work:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(H2:H4,K2+1)>0,K2+2,K2+1)
```

This assumes that your start number is in K2, and the range you're avoiding is H2:H4.

Comment: it is a mixture.  Some sequences that I want to reserve have several dozen sequential numbers in it. In other cases, they are not sequential.